# Meaning of "recognise" in : We also recognise the need to learn about business concepts

Tags: meaning-in-context

In my exam, I came across the following sentence:

As business English teachers, we know how important it is to learn the key business language.....
**We also recognise the need to learn about business concepts, developments in business and how business works in different cultures.**

Does "recognise" mean here:

- We know? In form of experience...(Working with it some years)
- We understand? In form of discern, realise (recognising)

The definitions given in the [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recognize):

> **recognize** verb (UK usually **recognise**) ...
>
> (KNOW) ​ B1 [ T ] to know someone or something because you have seen
>   or heard him or her or experienced it before:
>
> ... *Doctors are trained to recognize the symptoms of different diseases.*
>
> (ACCEPT) ​ B2 [ T ] to
>   accept that something is legal, true, or important:
>
> *The international community has refused to recognize (= officially accept the existence of) the newly independent nation state.*
>
> [ + (that) ] *He sadly recognized (that) he would die childless.*
>
> *You must recognize the seriousness of the problems we are facing.* ​
>
> [ENDORSE; VOICE APPROVAL] C1 [ T often passive ] If a person's
>   achievements are recognized, official approval is shown for them:
>
> *The Queen recognized his services to his country by awarding him an MBE.*

Comment: CED ? C4 ? /voice approval ?

Comment: It means 'accept, acknowledge the existence of" the need.

Comment: Actually, any of the Cambridge definitions quoted above would work, and they all mean essentially the same thing in this context.  (The word is not exceedingly precise, in this sense.)

Comment: 'And we are aware that there is the need, the _vital_ need, to ...' (so true and important).

Comment: In my eyes it is something between "discerning it" and "understanding it" , with a touch of accepting :-)

Comment: Must you post stuff with all those capital letters? It is really annoying and hard to read. You should make them lower case.

Answer (score 1):

The Cambridge English Dictionary's definition

> (ACCEPT) ​ B2 [ T ] to accept that something is legal, true, or
> important:

will explain the usage, except for how *recognise* came to mean that.

When *recognise* came into English it eventually displaced the word [aknow](https://www.etymonline.com/word/acknowledge):

> admit or show one's knowledge

Why that happened probably cannot be explained, as [recognise](https://www.etymonline.com/word/recognize)

> "resume possession of land,"

as it originally came into English barely touched on the idea of admitting something.
Why *aknow* went away,  or the current *acknowledge* isn't  used to the exclusion of *recognise* (admit, accept) may well remain a mystery.

> We also acknowledge the need to learn about business concepts, developments in business and how business works in different cultures

seems perfectly adequate , with no need for a word so heavily burdened as *recognise*.

Comment: That was my thought.